# Can ejb TransactionTimeout be changed at runtime?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

In EJB3 container-managed bean, I want to be able to allow extended timeout for nightly jobs.
How can I change

```
TransactionTimeout
```

setting for such use-cases?

Currently, code looks like this:

```
@TransactionTimeout(300)
public Result getResult() {
    //code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply annotate the EJB method that is being executed within the transaction as you noted above. My only suggestion is be more explicit in terms of the units. In this case I wait for an hour. Numerous TimeUnit.XXX's enumerated values are available.

```
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@TransactionTimeout(value=1, unit=TimeUnit.HOURS)
public void doSOmethingForALongTime() {

}
```

Comment: once annotated you can't change this!